# Any way to prevent linux kernel to migrate threads to other cpus

Tags: linux-kernel, pthreads

is there any way to prevent the linux kernel to migrate threads to other cpus?
Using hwloc (which in turn uses pthread_setaffinity_np), I bind threads to cores. However, sometimes I see that the kernel starts expensive migration tasks. Is there any way I can prevent the kernel of doing this? I have not found any flags in hwloc / the pthreads library, nor did setting kernel/sched_nr_migrate to 0 result in the desired behavior.
Any suggestions are highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Has anyone got any evidence that such a feature is an advantage in any app?  If thread X becomes ready, the core it is bound to is already busy and there is another core free, what is the OS supposed to do?  Not run it?  Migrate the other thread?  I don't see much upside?

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at libnuma. Not sure if it can be used in non NUMA arch.

Comment: @jrw: did you ever resolve this ? I'm seeing similar problems with short duration threads which seem to get migrated near the start of their life-time and this is killing performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the CPU affinity of the process (not the thread) and from what I understand the kernel will try real hard to respect that.  If you want all the threads that a particular process spawns to run on the same CPU then this is an acceptable solution.

Here's an article from IBM that gives some additional background and specific system calls:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-affinity/index.html